# python tkinter import portability

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm running the same very small python script from both my work computer at home and a server at work that that computer RDPs to. The server uses the company standard python 2 and I have been using python 3 at home. Recently I decided to use the same script to do the same job on both. Everything is the same and works except that one wants:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

and the other wants a single letter case change:

```
from tkinter import *
```

How do I make this portable as in the same script working on different python environments? I don't want to have two scripts to remember to keep an eye on.
Is it possible?

Comment: Your import lines can be within a `try/except ImportError` block, or you can test the version of python (using `sys.version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Python version and treat according to the case:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    from tkinter import *
else:
    from Tkinter import *
```

Answer (score 1):

The `2to3` program will perform (some, but not always perfect) translation of your program to Python 3. The trick is to write the code in such a way that your Python 2 *does* get successfully (and correctly) converted.

I'd recommend you take a look at [python-modernize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-modernize), which should help you maintain a compatible source.

Answer (score 0):

or try importing both of them :-)

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Simple. I didn't try it (not my style) but aliva's example should work in either environments--if one attempt at importing fails, the other attempt should work.